# extjs6 bind label visibility

Tags: data-binding, visibility, extjs6

I am looking to bind the visibility of a button to a parameter with some difficulty. In xamarin I would add binding in xaml to a parameter, then in viewmodel I would have a getter/setter and simply put my simple true/false formula in the getter.

What would be the equivalent in extjs. Right now in my view I have,

```
{
   xtype: 'button',
   text: 'Upload LiveEnd',
   //itemId: 'buttonUploadLiveEnd',
   handler: 'onUploadLiveEnding',
   margin: '5px 5px 0 0',
   bind: {
     hidden: '{param}'
   }
}
```

In my viewmodel I have a parameter

```
data: {
   param: true
}
```

That works to hide button, But when I try to change the variable in my controller it doesn't change the view even though I think the parameter is being changed. Is there something simpler like getter/setter from xamarin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the value of data fields of view model you can use the set method on viewmodel. So to achieve your target yo can use below syntax.

```
vm.set('param', false);
```

Here vm is the reference of your viewmodel.

Comment: thank you... that works!  is there a better way?  or something more sophisticated?